# We don't get something for nothing

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions-idiomatiques

> We don't get something for nothing.

[Grâce à lingue](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/get+something+for+nothing.html), j'ai trouvé les variantes suivantes :

> On n'obtient rien pour rien.
>
> On n'obtient pas quelque chose pour rien.
>
> On n'obtient rien sans rien.
>
> On n'a jamais rien pour rien.

Je me demande laquelle est plus idiomatique et s'il y a d'autres expressions qui interprètent le même sens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toutes ces formules sont idiomatiques, c'est à dire qu'il n'y a pas de mot qui n'aille pas avec les autres selon le contexte; par exemple dans le contexte de ce qui peut être demandé et obtenu d'un organisme public la réponse « On n'obtient pas quelque chose pour rien. » convient au contexte en plus que d'être idiomatique; dans ce cas particulier, de même certaines des autres  possibilités sont utilisable.

Le critère serait donc, non sur le plan de ce qui est idiomatique ou non, mais sur le plan de ce qui est contextuel.

Comme il est à peu près sûr que le contexte est celui de l'énonciation en tant qu'adage et non pas d'une énonciations attachées à une situation particulière de l'existence ou à un ensemble de telles situations la seule qui soit contextuelle est la dernière (On n'a jamais rien pour rien.). On pourrait la simplifier et dire « On n'a rien pour rien. » et elle serait toujours contextuelle.

Les trois premières ne conviennent pas si bien parce que, me semble-t-il, le verbe « obtenir » manque de généralité.

Answer (score 3):

> On n'a rien sans rien

est la bonne manière de dire. Je n'ai jamais rencontré les autres formes.